# How to fix sass from compiling single quotes to double quote in css

Tags: css, sass

while trying to insert a background image using sass, URL('') compiles in css as URL(""). how do i prevent the double quote?

Answer (score 0):

That is per the [CSS standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#urls). You can also state the URL without any quotes at all, if the double quotes bother you.

> ### The following statements are identical:
>
> @import url("base-theme.css");
>
> @import "base-theme.css";

Comment: Thanks. i was able to figure the bug...the error was from the id selector....double or single quote doesn't invalidate the code....gracias

Comment: The spec you linked doesn't support what you're saying. The spec https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#strings says "double quotes or single quotes"